# 4x4 square with no increasing triples

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, latin-square

Can you fill a 4x4 grid with numbers from 1 to 4 such that:

- Every number occurs exactly once in each row and in each column (Latin square).
- No row or column contains 3 adjacent numbers that are all in increasing or decreasing order. For example you cannot have "1, 2, 3" or "3, 2, 1", but you can have "1, 3, 2".

Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example

> ```
>  1  3  2  4
>  3  1  4  2
>  2  4  1  3
>  4  2  3  1
> ```

Comment: Correct and very fast!